# Software RAID failed to mount after apt-get upgrade

Tags: linux, raid, mount, software-raid

I have a software RAID 10 (jfs) on an ubuntu 12.10 and require some assistance repairing the RAID after it failed to mount after a routine apt-get upgrade followed by a reboot.

```
/dev/md0:

Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Mon Jan  7 20:42:27 2013
Raid Level : raid10
Array Size : 3904809984 (3723.92 GiB 3998.53 GB)
Used Dev Size : 1952404992 (1861.96 GiB 1999.26 GB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 3
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Mon Mar 18 19:34:08 2013
State : active, degraded 
Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

Layout : near=2
Chunk Size : 512K

Name : bert-serer:0  (local to host bert-serer)
UUID : 56fe0043:180dcd27:4760f54f:f77af72e
Events : 202109

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
   1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
   2       0        0        2      removed
   3       8       50        3      active sync   /dev/sdd2
```

Comment: would booting from a live disk and then trying to reassemble the array work. mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sd[abcd]2

Comment: Why would you need to boot from a live disk, rather then issue the command from your active install ?

Comment: I need to un mount the disk first and as my boot in on that drive, the drive is busy.